# Package: Hypervolume "ununsed Argument: bandwith"

Tags: r, r-package, unused-variables

I have a question about the Hypervolume Package in R.
I´m working on rangesize of mamals and their climatic conditions. So i got a Code from a former student and try to rerun it.

For the analysis i need to build a hypervolume out of a large data.frame

here just a little example: (i try to create a dataset, so i can upload a full code)

If i run this
 `hv <- hypervolume(data, bandwidth = 1)`
i get always the same error:

Error in hypervolume_threshold(hv_gaussian, quantile.requested = quantile.requested,  :   unused argument (bandwidth = 1)

if i delete the `bandwidth =1` the programm runs, but i get 3 different warnings:

1: "Some dimensions have much more higher standard deviations than others:"

2: In hypervolume(data) :
Consider removing some axes.

3: In hypervolume(data) :
Log number of observations (3.74) is less than or equal to the number of dimensions (4).
You may not have enough data to accurately estimate a hypervolume with this dimensionality.
Consider reducing the dimensionality of the analysis.

I read the package description and tried a while to fix the problem, I used different bandwidths, i tried different scales of records/datasets(small to big). But i get always the same errors or warnings.

I´m not a expert on the Hypervolume-Package, so maybe someone can help me pls.
(I try to create a little dataset so i can post a full code here)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the arguments to the hypervolume function have changed over the years. A cursory look at [the source code](https://github.com/cran/hypervolume/releases) suggests that `bandwidth` was an argument in versions 1.x but not in versions 2.x.

Either you can install an old version using `devtools::install_github()` or you can check if one of the arguments to `hypervolume_gaussian()` does what you need - `kde.bandwidth` looks possible, but I don't know enough about the method to be certain.